# Can't enable HTTPS and SSL streams in PHP no matter what

Tags: linux, php, ssl, https, openssl

I've been trying to enable my HTTPS/SSL (443) streams in PHP but no had success at all.
My certs are properly installed and **I can normally browse through the site using HTTPS**, but phpinfo() tells that such streams are not installed, at least for PHP.

This is the actual error I'm having with php:

`ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195... Thu, 14 Mar 2013 19:44:40 +0100 ApnsPHP3893: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`

I'm using:

- 64bit SUSE Linux AMI from Amazon
- Apache 2.2.12
- PHP 5.2.14
- MySQL working fine

Phpinfo() tells me:

```
additional .ini files parsed: /etc/php5/conf.d/ctype.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/curl.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/dom.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/gd.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/hash.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/iconv.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/json.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/mbstring.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/openssl.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/pcntl.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/soap.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/sqlite.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/tokenizer.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/xmlreader.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php5/conf.d/zip.ini

Registered PHP Streams: php, file, data, http, ftp
Registered Stream Socket Transports: tcp, udp, unix, udg

cURL support enabled
cURL Information libcurl/7.19.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8j zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.10
```

Mod_ssl also shows under the loaded modules section and extension=openssl.so is properly set in php.ini as well.

Someone has told me to try `php -i | grep 'Configure Command'`, which resulted in the following error:

`php: error while loading shared libraries: libmm.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP stream includes HTTPS as of PHP 4.3.0, it's not a separate stream in `phpinfo()`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php

Comment: Thanks. Why those streams don't show at my phpinfo() output and in fact they're not working. I can't connect SSL to other sites, it says the stream type is not available... Comparing to other servers, I understand that https, ssl and ftps should be at the Registered PHP Streams.

Comment: Are you trying to use `ssl://` URLs? Use `https://`.

Comment: The HTTPS stream is listed as "http", which covers HTTP and HTTPS. The FTPS stream is listed as "ftp", which covers FTP and FTPS. The doc I linked makes this pretty clear...

Comment: I can browse my site using https without problems. I can also connect using ssh, just can't see the https, ssh php registered streams using phpinfo(). When I compare to other servers with the exact same configuration, they show those protocols available, hence the code I mentioned works in those different servers.

Comment: Browsing your own site has **nothing** to do with the available streams, that's handled by your webserver, not PHP.

Comment: I got it. Basically you're saying that probably the streams are available, but they just dont show explicitly. So why I get the error when I try to connect to another address using ssl and when I remove the SSH, it works fine? Example: ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

Thu, 14 Mar 2013 19:44:40 +0100 ApnsPHP3893: ERROR: Unable to connect to 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195': Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: SSH requires a PECL extension and is used via `ssh2://`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php `ssl://` doesn't appear to exist. http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php **Read the pages on supported protocols and wrappers I'm linking repeatedly to, please.** You may want to use `fsockopen`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm considering re-compile PHP, so the ssl and https protocols/streams are supported by it. I figure out that when these protocols/streams are not shown with phpinfo() it means they're really not available, differently than: "HTTPS stream is listed as "http", which covers HTTP and HTTPS. The FTPS stream is listed as "ftp", which covers FTP and FTPS"